# How to check the project/.exe file

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have 3 projects, (Ex. project1, project2, project3). Some parts of these projects are using just 1 Form (frmDetails) placed on a separate folder.

I want to Disable some details on my form depends on what project I open.

For example, I opened Project1 - all details on my form are displayed. Then when I opened project2 - I want "Age" and "Birthday" set Visible to false.

What functions that I need to this?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do that, is to make 3 separate copies of the form for 3 projects and modify them as needed. 
If you wish, you could create a class from that form with minimal objects that appear in every project, and create 3 separate forms from that class per project.

Normally, after you build an executable, executable doesn't know from which project it was build. So you can't basically have one form behaving differently per project. However, per project you might add something that tells the project (be it a text, xml, Json, dbf ... file). So you could read that file's content in load or init of form and set form objects' visibility on\off if you want to do it with just a single form. It would make things harder and would be confusing but at the end it might sound 'nice' since it is only a single form. My suggestion, as said on top, create 3 separate copies per project. That way it is much easier to control them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an application object, you can have a property of that object that identifies the project. However, I'd be more likely to do this in a more generic way that specifically looking at a single property.

You might use a set of logical properties that indicate options you can turn on and off, and then you can check those properties in your forms.